# How to get GTM's built-in YouTube trigger to fire on videos played in modal created via JS click function

Tags: google-analytics, bootstrap-4, youtube-api, bootstrap-modal, google-tag-manager

I have a page setup that displays several images that when clicked play their respective YouTube video within a modal. This works fine, however I am now wanting to implement some tracking (Google Analytics) to provide insights into plays, pauses, skips, percent watched, etc. I am already loading GA via a GTM container, so I am attempting to utilize GTM's built-in YouTube trigger to fire a GA event tag. So far I have been unable to get the YouTube trigger to fire.

You can view the live page here: https://ww5.komen.org/yourone/

This page uses Bootstrap and relies on the Bootstrap modal to display the videos. I am using GTM's preview mode to determine which tags are firing. I have tried checking the trigger configuration checkbox to add JavaScript API support to all YouTube videos, and this doesn't seem to have any effect on the firing of the GTM trigger.

I have the following configured within GTM:

**Variables:**

- All built-in video data layer variables activated
- A user-defined {{Video Actions}} variable that is a lookup table with inputs (start, pause, progress, seek, buffering, complete) matched to outputs (Start Playing, Pause, Watched {{Video Percent}}%, Skipped Forward (or Back), Buffering, Reached the End)

**Triggers:**

- YouTube Video trigger set to capture start, complete, pause, seeking and buffering, progress (percentages 25,50,75), Add JS API support to all YouTube videos, firing on all videos

**Tags:**

- GA Universal Analytics tag with track type: YouTube, category: YouTube, Action: {{Video Actions}}, label: {{Video Title}} - {{Video URL}}, GA settings: {{GA Tracking ID}} firing on YouTube Video trigger

Here is the code that spawns the modal:

```
<a class="video-btn video-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxqEcA7p-pE" data-target="#YTmodal">
  <div class="card-img-top" style="background: #f7f7f7 url('img/cards/cathy-and-donnie.jpg'); background-size: cover; height: 225px; width: 100%; position: relative;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <p class="intro">Meet Donny Coursey<br /> and his wife, <span class="pink-text">Cathy</span></p>
    <p class="quote">"Our love is<br />stronger than cancer"</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here is the modal code (hidden until activated):

```
<!-- VIDEO MODAL HIDDEN UNTIL ACTIVATED -->
<div class="modal fade" id="YTmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>

      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END VIDEO MODAL -->
```

Here is the JS that creates the modals:

```
<!-- YOUTUBE VIDEO MODALS -->
<script>
$(".video-modal").click(function () {
  var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
      videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
      videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1";
  $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
  $(theModal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
  });
});
</script>
<!-- END YOUTUBE VIDEO MODALS -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-youtube-video-trigger-in-google-tag-manager/

Basically, stated in the section 'Track lazy-loaded / dynamically inserted videos' if you add `<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api">` to the page, it'll work.

Comment: This worked for me. I had videos loading dynamically with Magnific Popup Plugin, and once I added this, the video events are now showing in GTM. Thanks!